# Did Star Trek have any episode (in any of the incarnations or even novelizations) inspired by ultra high-g creatures in Dragon's Egg?

Tags: star-trek, plot-device

I ask this because since the original series, Star Trek has done a real decent job apparently of employing qualified technical advisors. Only Star Trek seemed to understand astronomical distances even in OS -- the distance to Andromeda was handled very accurately. What OS's competition like Outer Limits did with things like that was unspeakable often.

Anyway, I would guess the aliens in Dragon's Egg would be too unsympathetic -- but perhaps some story had humanoids who were from a very high g planet, maybe exhibiting same phobia the about falling that DE's creatures do?

I think STOS actually anticipated DE in a story about a people operating many times faster than we do, not the same scale but so fast they can't be seen but can heard. (That was realistic -- when something is dropped into Kirk's coffee, that can be heard, very nice detail.)

Comment: You should edit this down to does trek have any stories about gravity phobias before the down votes roll in.  And leave the other franchises out for obvious recent reasons.   Tos wink of an eye and voy blink ofban eye beingvthe time accelerated stories which are not your question.

Comment: If you found an episode about creatures living on a very high gravity world, why would you suppose that it was inspired by *Dragon's Egg* rather than the much more famous novel *Mission of Gravity*?

Comment: @user14111: I would not assume unless some detail like neutron star was mentioned.

Comment: Maybe I don't know the Star Trek universe well enough, but "astronomical distances even in OS" what is "OS"? What is "STOS"? I've learned that "TOS" is "The Original Series" (from the 60's), is this just a longer form of that?

Comment: Original Series or Star Trek the Original Series. The episode where aliens from Andromeda want to return with the Enterprise in STOS shows that the writers understood what 2 million light years meant -- even at 1000 times the speed of light, it would take 2000 years, kind of mind boggling. As good as taking this distance into account, relativity is never mentioned, maybe because their propulsion system somehow gets around relativity.